# Pass array into each object in JSON file. (Proc JSON SAS)

Tags: arrays, json, sas

I'm trying to export a dataset to a JSON file. With PROC JSON every row in my dataset is exported nicely.
What I want to do is to add an array into each exported object with data from a specific column.

My dataset has structure like this:

```
data test;
input id $ amount $ dimension $;
datalines;
1 x A
1 x B
1 x C
2 y A
2 y X
3 z C
3 z K
3 z X
;
run; 

proc json out='/MYPATH/jsontest.json' pretty nosastags; 
     export test; 
run;
```

And the exported JSON object looks, obviously, like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "amount": "x",
    "dimension": "A"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "amount": "x",
    "dimension": "B"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "amount": "x",
    "dimension": "C"
  },
...]
```

**The result I want:**

For each id I would like to insert all of the data from the dimension column into an array so my output would look this this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "amount": "x",
    "dimensions": [
      "A",
      "B",
      "C"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "amount": "y",
    "dimensions": [
      "A",
      "X"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "amount": "z",
    "dimensions": [
      "C",
      "K",
      "X"
    ]
  }
]
```

I've not been able to find a scenario like this or some guidelines on how to solve my problem. I hope somebody can help.

/Crellee

Answer (score 2):

There are other methods for json output, including

- hand-coded emitter in DATA Step
- JSON package in Proc DS2

Here is an example of a hand-coded emitter for your data and desired mapping.

```
data _null_;
  file 'c:\temp\test.json';

  put '[';

  do group_counter = 1 by 1 while (not end_of_data);
    if group_counter > 1 then put @2  ',';
    put @2 '{';
    do dimension_counter = 1 by 1 until (last.amount);
      set test end=end_of_data;
      by id amount;
      if dimension_counter = 1 then do;
        q1 = quote(trim(id));
        q2 = quote(trim(amount));
        put 
          @4 '"id":' q1 "," 
        / @4 '"amount":' q1 "," 
        ;
        put @4 '"dimensions":' / @4 '[';
      end;
      else do;
        put @6 ',' @;
      end;
      q3 = quote(trim(dimension));
      put @8 q3;
    end;
    if dimension_counter > 1 then put @4 '}';
    put @2 ']';
  end;

  put ']';

  stop;
run;
```

Such an emitter can be macro-ized and generalized to handle specifications of data=, by= and arrayify=.  Not a path recommended for friends.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a nice solution! It's not so dynamic as I could hope for. But perhaps the proc json cannot solve the issue i'm standing with.

Answer (score 1):

You can try concatenating / grouping the text before calling `proc json`.

I don't have `proc json` in my SAS environment, but try this step and see it works for you:

```
data want;
set test (rename=(dimension=old_dimension));
Length dimension $200. ;
retain dimension ;
by id    amount   notsorted;
if first.amount = 1 then do; dimension=''; end;
if last.amount = 1 then do; dimension=catx(',',dimension,old_dimension);  output; end;
else do; dimension=catx(',',dimension,old_dimension); end;
drop old_dimension;
run;
```

Output:

```
id=1 amount=x dimension=A,B,C 
id=2 amount=y dimension=A,X 
id=3 amount=z dimension=C,K,X
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't resolve my problem since I still won't have an array in my JSON object, but a key with a value of .."A,B,C".
But thank you  very much for your answer!